# adb port forwarding and socket connection

Tags: android, python-2.7, sockets, adb, portforwarding

Situation-

I have two android devices with a server app installed in it. App listens in a particular port. I have forwarded one local port to device-1's server port and connected to it. I am able to communicate with server app.
I tried forwarding same local port and connected to device-2's server port. And i am able to communicate with device-2 and device-1.

With the two socket connections i made, I can separately communicate with two devices using same local port.

Question-

I wonder how this works. same local port is forwarded to two different paths.
My understanding was in the low level everything goes through the port which we mention at time of socket connection. Which is wrong? Port is used `only` at time of connection and there after some other connection handle is used for communication ?

```
<Run device 1 server>
adb -s serial1 forward tcp:8088 tcp:8088
connect to device-1 # I used python

<Run device 2 server>
adb -s serial2 forward tcp:8088 tcp:8088
connect to device-2 # I used python
```